# How do I change my product image without distorting it?

Tags: image

How do I change my product image without distorting it?  I have changed the image size to reflect but it still stretch.  The Hoover image is not distorted.
You can see there.
http://secretlyspoiled.com/girls/little-girl-tan-purse

Answer (score 2):

You have a fixed width and height on the image. Both of them are `400px`.
Edit `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` and remove the width and height from the `img` tag with class `mediaZoomerMain-image`.

The template may be different if you have custom extensions installed.
If this is the case, turn on the [template path hints](http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/) to see what template you need to edit.